Is it possible to formalize the notion of choosing a random subset of a given measure from $[0,1]$?
I think the question has been asked before but a cursory google search and stack search did not really produce anything conclusive, so here's my quesiton.
As in the title

I am looking for a formal notion of picking a random
subset of $[0,1]$ of a certain measure. More formally, is there a way
to give a (kind of uniform) measure to the set of all Lebesgue
measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ of measure $0\le d\le 1$ (say)?


What I have found is this unanswered question, where a commenter mentions that it is indeed possible, but there was no reply upon asking for a rigorous notion.
I have also found this mathoverflow discussion. I believe this answers my question in the negative, but I am in no way sure how.
In one of the comments of the mathoverflow discussion, there was a link to a terry tao blog which looks at an intuitive way to generate a random subset of $[0,1]$: namely, toss a coin with probability $1/2$ for each real number in $[0,1]$, keep the number if you get a head and look at the subset. Intuitively, this should have a measure of $1/2$, but the post veers away from this discussion to constructing a non-measurable set using non-standard analysis. This idea does look promising, and I would be interested in seeing if this pans out in some form.

Obviously there can be no algorithm (in the sense of computers) to do this. But I am looking for any way to do this - constructively, non-constructively etc; uncountable coin tosses, using filters etc are all par for the game. If there are results that can be gained by assuming/not-assuming axiom of choice, I will still be interested (I mention this because in the Solovay model, all subsets of $\mathbb R$ are measurable, and hence also of $[0,1]$ and aybe this can be leveraged).

Please feel free to ask for clarifications since this is not really a very clean question. Any help is appreciated!

I have not thought about it deeply, but one possibility is starting from the Hausdorff metric over a Polish space $M$ (in particular, $[0,1]$) that will induce a Polish topology over the set of non-empty compact subsets of $M$, say $M'$. There should be a way to define a Lebesgue measure over the new space $M'$.

@HanulJeon I am very weakly familiar with Polish spaces, but this seems like a good idea that I really haven't given any thought to. If you can flesh it out, it would be really nice. I am suurprised there is no canonical answer to this (yet :p) I thought this question has been asked before and probably has a well known answer.

Other than just assigning every subset a measure of $0$, it seems like what you’re proposing is impossible due to the finite additivity requirement for measures. Like, if every singleton set (set with just one real number element) has measure $m>0$, then you aren’t allowed to also assign measure $m$ to sets of two real numbers.

Let $X$ be a topological space. Define $\mathcal{F}:=\mathcal{F}(X) := \{ F\subseteq X \ | \ F \text{ closed}\} \subseteq P(X)$ (where $P(X)$ is the power set). Endow $\mathcal{F}$ with the Fell topology (or hit-or-miss topology) $\tau$. This topology is the topology generated by the sets $ \{ F \in \mathcal{F} \ | \ F \cap U \neq \emptyset\}, U\subseteq X \ \text{open}$ and $ \{ F \in \mathcal{F} \ | \ F \cap C = \emptyset\}, C\subseteq X \ \text{compact}$.
Now consider the measureable space $(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{F}))$ (where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra). A random (closed) set is now simply a random variable $S: (\Omega, \mathcal{A}) \to (\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{F}))$, where $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ is a probability space.
For $X= [0,1]$ one could pick a probability measure on the subset $ \{F \in \mathcal{F}([0,1])\ | \ \lambda(F) = d \ \}\subseteq\mathcal{F}([0,1])$ with the induced sigma algebra.

This seems intriguing. Can you shed some light on why this topology (and it's associated borel sigma algebra) is natural/intuitive to consider?
